# Black screen before booting up windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I have this problem that even before booting into Win7, my laptop gets stuck in a black screen with a blinking keyboard cursor on it.
It happened after I formatted one of my other partitions.
I have tried everything including `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /fixboot`, and I have even tried using Ubuntu grub to boot windows but unfortunately even grub does not identify my Windows installation.
I really don't want to do a reinstalltion of Windows...

Comment: Did you format the partition Windows 7 was installed on? That's what it sounds like.

Comment: And I am supposed to know that how? I was just asking a question. No need to get your panties in a bunch. Good luck. Hope you get it figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Insert the Windows 7 installation DVD and boot from your DVD drive. You may have to change the boot order through system BIOS to boot from your DVD.
2. Choose your default "Language," "Time" and "Keyboard Input" on the first window and click "Next."
3. Click on the "Repair Your Computer" option to gain access to the System Recovery window. Now choose "Command Prompt" to run the Bootsect.exe utility. Bootsect is located inside the boot folder so change your directory to boot. Now run

> bootsect /nt60 C:\

if you had Windows 7 initially installed in the C partition. Alternatively, you can run

> bootsect /nt60 SYS

or >

> bootsect /nt60 ALL

to repair the SYStem partition or ALL partitions. Eject the DVD and restart your computer. Your computer should now boot Windows 7 again.



[Source of Information](http://www.ehow.com/how_4836283_repair-mbr-windows.html)


[Microsoft bootsect command meanings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744577%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the recovery environment:

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```